# Can Prawn generate PDFs in CMYK format?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn, cmyk

My client says that the generated PDFs must be in CMYK format. Can Prawn do this?

I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Prawn can do this. This topic seems to be omit by documentation, so that you can look at source code. [This example](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/blob/stable/examples/graphics/cmyk.rb) demonstrates Prawn's support for CMYK images and colors. For example, Prawn::Graphics::Color#fill_color take either one argument or four arguments. If a single argument is provided, it should be a 6 digit HTML color. If 4 arguments are provided, the color is assumed to be a CMYK value.